# Is there a plugin for setting breakpoints in an element?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I regularly detect window width via enquire.js or media queries, but what if I want to style things differently based on the width of an element, say a div, and then change the appearance of its children based on its width? Thanks. I'm using SASS if that helps.

Comment: Your title seems to be quite different from your actual question.

Comment: well, a plugin could be the solution, or there could be another way.

Comment: i found breakpoints.js, but they're applying it to the window object. i'm wondering if it could be applied to a dom element...?